# Cannot find module '@storybook/react' or its corresponding type declarations. ts(2307)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rollupjs

maybe someone knows how to solve this error. Moreover, if you import it in a file in the root directory, everything works and there are no errors.I couldn't find anything useful on the internet

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owZRY.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6lEm.png)